# Can't use Control.FindControl on dynamically created System.Web.UI.WebControl

Tags: asp.net, .net

Why would the following code not work? I am creating a control, adding a child control and attempting to retrieve it by id using the .FindControl method.

```
[Test]
    public void TryToFindControl()
    {
        var myPanel = new Panel();
        var textField = new TextBox
        {
            ID = "mycontrol"
        };
        myPanel.Controls.Add(textField);

        var foundControl = myPanel.FindControl("mycontrol");

        // this fails
        Assert.IsNotNull(foundControl);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: I'm trying to do some unit testing outside of the context of an actual aspx page. Guess I can't use FindControl but there are various other ways.

Comment: So you have my answer :) but why would you unit test if the Control has been added? Or you explicitly testing FindControl method? Anyhow for me the topic is closed :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. That isn't the exact test that I'm trying to write. I've just simplified down to the problem that I'm running into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Panel** has not been added to **Page** yet, so you cannot use **FindControl**. Instead, you need to find it inside **Panel.Controls**

```
[TestMethod]
public void TryToFindControl()
{
    var myPanel = new Panel();
    var textField = new TextBox
    {
        ID = "mycontrol"
    };
    myPanel.Controls.Add(textField);

    var foundControl = myPanel.Controls
        .OfType<TextBox>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == "mycontrol");

    Assert.IsNotNull(foundControl);
}
```

### Testing with Page

**FindControl** works only if **container** is added to Page.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myPanel = new Panel();
        var textField = new TextBox
        {
            ID = "mycontrol"
        };
        myPanel.Controls.Add(textField);

        Controls.Add(myPanel);

        // foundControl is not null anymore!
        var foundControl = myPanel.FindControl("mycontrol");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The control must be part of the server side `Page` control collection hierarchy to be found.

```
public void TryToFindControl()
{
    var myPanel = new Panel();

    // key line here
    Page.Controls.Add(myPanel); 

    var textField = new TextBox
    {
        ID = "mycontrol"
    };

    myPanel.Controls.Add(textField);

    var foundControl = myPanel.FindControl("mycontrol");

    Assert.IsNotNull(foundControl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'll start form the fact I don't know of System.UI.Control, Rather `System.Web.UI.Control`

Then I could not find `TextField` Control so I used Web `TextBox` instead. Please adjust your code as necessary. I also used VS Test attributes

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void TryToFindControl()
    {
        var editContainer = new HtmlTableCell();
        editContainer.Controls.Add(new TextBox
        {
            ID = "mycontrol",
        });

        System.Web.UI.Control foundControl = null;

        foreach (System.Web.UI.Control ctrl in editContainer.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl.ID == "mycontrol")
            {
                foundControl = ctrl;
                break;
            }
        }

        // This works
        Assert.IsNotNull(foundControl);
    }
```

Based on your exact wording, if you want to access the control you added, create an instance first as variable, so you can access it directly. Please keep in mind that I don't know what you are trying to achieve globally, so my answer(s) may not apply because of that, or there maybe be better solution.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void TryToFindControl()
    {
        var editContainer = new HtmlTableCell();

        var foundControl = new TextBox
        {
            ID = "mycontrol"
        };

        editContainer.Controls.Add(foundControl);

        // This works
        Assert.IsNotNull(foundControl);
    }
```